# Is there a free, preferrably open-source, stand-alone clone of Activestate's Komodo Rx Toolkit?

Tags: regex, open-source, komodo

I find the regular expression toolkit tool in Komodo 4.1 pretty handy.  Trouble is you have to dish out $300 for Komodo to use it.  I'd love the same functionality in a stand alone tool... any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Komodo 5.2 is the latest version, FYI.

Comment: I just found https://www.debuggex.com and it's pretty awesome looking, it provides an interesting visual map of what your regex pattern is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the JavaScript regular expression engine is acceptable, there's [a nice one written by Erik Arvidsson](http://erik.eae.net/playground/regexp/regexp.html). It doesn't have the "Replace" features that Komodo IDE's Rx Toolkit has, but it's helpful for testing matches.

He wrote [for use with Komodo Edit](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/22/16.34.22/) - I guess he didn't want to shell out for the IDE either. ;)

Disclosure: Sridhar and I work for ActiveState, so we tend to push [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/). If $295 is a barrier for you, just tell our sales folks that you're a friend of Sridhar from stackoverflow and they might be able to swing a deal for you. We'll take it out of his pay.

Update: More shilling if that's OK. There's a sale on till the end of October. $50 off!

Comment: As stated elsewhere, I need the replace feature, so the first link's no good. However, the second link has a comment with a link to a tool that will do the trick: http://osteele.com/tools/rework/#. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be more than happy to pay for the RX tool, I just don't have any other use for the IDE. Maybe you guys could spin it off into a separate product?

Comment: I used the ide and wouldn't use it again. But i really miss this toolkit. Please consider separating it.

Answer (score 1):

I have occasionally used the [Regular Expression Labratory](http://www.silveragesoftware.com/rxl.html)

Comment: Thanks - that's the idea, but it seems buggy - for instance, it throws an error on a simple ".*"... I'd accept your answer otherwise.

Comment: Second the buggy comment! Also its very vauge on the Re syntax actually supported (perl, pcre, sed, awk etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Give the open-source app **[Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/)** a try.

[image]

But I suggest that you use Komodo (do you want a discount?) - it contains much more features than Rx toolkit.

Comment: Thanks, but the replace feature is a must.  I have a komodo license (kudos!), but I'd prefer something stand-alone so it launches quicker, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I love this [Adobe Air tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/). Great for testing out expressions before trying them in the wild. It is a desktop app version of the online tool that he provides - all free.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think this site rocks! It has match and replace. Try it and let me know:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

Damian Conway made a free regular expression debugger module that allows you to visualize a regular expression as it backtracks, fails, and/or matches: [Regexp::Debugger](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Debugger-0.001011/lib/Regexp/Debugger.pm).

Video of it in action: [Damian Conway on Regexp::Debugger at YAPC::NA 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcSFIUiMgAs#t=2m52s)